# How to use content slide with RECORD objects in typoscript

Tags: slide, typo3, typoscript

On one of my sites, content (Videos) is inherited from the levels above if the content column is empty (in this case: `colPos=3` / Border)

To create the output, I use

```
temp.myObject < styles.content.getBorder
temp.myObject {
    slide = -1
}
```

Easy, because this is taken from a CONTENT object and `slide` is a built-in function.

Due to our system setup I need to do something similar with the RECORDS object. But the following typoscript doesn't work - it generates empty output:

```
temp.myObject = RECORDS
temp.myObject {
    tables = tt_content
    source.cObject = CONTENT
    source.cObject {
        slide = -1
        table = tt_content
        renderObj = TEXT
        renderObj.field = uid
    }
}
```

The same happens with this snippet:

```
temp.myObject = RECORDS
temp.myObject {
    tables = tt_content
    source.cObject = CONTENT
    source.cObject {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            pidInList.data = leveluid:-1,slide
        }
        renderObj = TEXT
        renderObj.field = uid
    }
}
```

[Note: The complicated `source` part above provides the ID of a content element from where we extract an image file from the flexform xml]

Can somebody help me to achieve a contentslide solution based on the RECORDS object?
If there are any problems understanding the questions, please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CONTENT object doesn't have "slide" property.

Try simulate slide using stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject.... for Your RECORDS object, as it could be done for slide simulation for TYPO3 3.8.x.

Example on TYPO3 wiki :

http://wiki.typo3.org/wiki/Content_Slide#Content_Sliding_in_TYPO3_3.8.x_by_TS_only

Comment: I suspected that it would make our setup even more complicated, therefore I used a quick workaround to satisfy our client's needs. Thanks for the hint - it might take some time until I try that and confirm.